# Python sort() with lambda key - list of nums vs chars

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda

I am trying to apply the solution of sorting a list of numbers by frequency of each number, but to a list of chars.

My solution for sorting the numbers is:

```
def num_sort_by_freq(list_of_nums):

    num_count = {}

    for num in list_of_nums:
        if num not in num_count:
            num_count[num] = 1
        else:
            num_count[num] += 1

    list_of_nums.sort(key = lambda x:num_count[x])

    return list_of_nums

print(num_sort_by_freq([1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]))
```

Output: [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Trying to sort the chars:

```
def char_sort_by_freq(string_to_be_list):

    list_of_chars = list(string_to_be_list)

    char_count = {}

    for char in list_of_chars:
        if char not in char_count:
            char_count[char] = 1
        else:
            char_count[char] += 1

    list_of_chars.sort(key = lambda x:char_count[x])

    return "".join(list_of_chars)

print(char_sort_by_freq("asdfasdfasdddffffff"))
```

Output: asasasdddddffffffff

Expected output: aaasssdddddffffffff

I've gone through it too many times and cannot understand why the output's 'a's and 's's are jumbled together, rather than sequential.

Any help is appreciated.

edit: Thanks so much for the help! Lambda functions are new territory for me.

Comment: Your string has the same number of `a` and `s`, so `sort` simply leaves them in the same order it found them: alternating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your `key` function to return `tuple` to handle ties:

```
def char_sort_by_freq(string_to_be_list):

    list_of_chars = list(string_to_be_list)

    char_count = {}

    for char in list_of_chars:
        if char not in char_count:
            char_count[char] = 1
        else:
            char_count[char] += 1

    list_of_chars.sort(key = lambda x:(char_count[x], x))
    #                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return "".join(list_of_chars)

print(char_sort_by_freq("asdfasdfasdddffffff"))
```

Output:

```
aaasssdddddffffffff
```